# How to find out if you have colab pro or not inside colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

This is more of a miscellaneous question but is there a feature to do this?
I just simply can't find any documentation on this topic.
For instance, my usage would be like this:

```
from google.colab import utils # I made this up
colab_pro = utils.colab_is_pro()
if colab_pro:
  # train model with higher settings
else:
  # train model with lower settings
```

Currently I do have a way of doing this, but it's rather hacky:

```
gpu_name = !nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv
# You get Tesla T4 with free colab and faster GPUs with colab pro
colab_pro = False if 'T4' in gpu_name else True
```

FYI, here is the colab I'm working on:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/Namburger/edgetpu-ssdlite-mobiledet-retrain/blob/master/ssdlite_mobiledet_transfer_learning_cat_vs_dog.ipynb#scrollTo=Mg1C8UwStK7i

Answer (score 5):

```
#A Colab pro environment should have >20Gb of total memory.
from psutil import virtual_memory
colab_pro = virtual_memory().total / 1e9
print('Your runtime has {:.1f} gigabytes of available RAM\n'.format(colab_pro))

if colab_pro < 20:
  print('Not using a high-RAM runtime')
  # train model with lower settings
else:
  print('You are using a high-RAM runtime!')
  # train model with higher settings
```

Also, you can check the available memory in colab as follows:

```
!cat /proc/meminfo
```

A Colab pro environment should have >20Gb of total memory.

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/pro.ipynb#scrollTo=V1G82GuO-tez